# Can an author change the name listed on her book’s copyright page to a new one when she republishes the book?

Tags: copyright-transfer

I previously published books under a pen name through a publisher that has since closed due to the owner’s death. I’m planning to self-publish the books but under a new author name. Can I change the name listed in the copyright page of the book to the new name, e.g. copyright@2011 by Old Name to copyright@2011 by New Name, or add the new name, e.g. copyright@2011 by Old Name/New Name? Or must I maintain the original name? Any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually submit this for copyright to the copyright office, or just declared it on your book?

Comment: Pen names are up to an author to choose afaik - by now everybody knows that "[Richard Bachmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Bachman)" is actually Stephen king, and books that had been published as Bachmann now are published under King. He even supplied a fake author photo!

Answer (score 1):

### You are not your name

The copyright is owned by you. What you call yourself is immaterial.

Not only aren’t you going to sue yourself for copyright violation; you can’t. First, because you clearly gave yourself permission and second, because, except in some highly specific situations involving trusts, you can’t sue yourself for anything.